# How many httphandlers and httpmodules we can have in one asp.net application?

Tags: asp.net, httphandler, httpmodule

I am currently studying HttpHandlers and HttpModules in ASP.Net.

One question that is coming in my mind again and again is.....

How many total HttpHandlers and HttpModules that one application can have?

Is there any max limit for custom handlers and modules?

Can we have more than one custom module for one event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as im aware you can only have one handler per request and as many modules as you like.

Comment: So per request means for each file type? right? One handler for .aspx pages, one for .php pages, one for .html pages